# How to update warning in webstorm?

Tags: webstorm, deprecated

I've been developing node js app which use mongodb to manipulate static data. I'm using webstorm to my main editor program.

I wrote a function which use mongodb to find a data. Actually, this is sample code in the mongodb's getting started document.

```
var findRestaurants = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor =db.collection('restaurants').find( );
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            console.dir(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
```

In the 3rd line, `each` is the method of the cursor object which defined in mongodb driver api. This method operate the callback function to the returned records which the cursor pointing to, and there's no problem to run this code.

But, in the webstorm editor window, the program gives warning to `each` method, saying that this symbol is deprecated. It says that javascript has deprecated this `each` method. It may seems that webstorm doesn't know about the api information of node js or mongodb. Of course, I could ignore this message, but it makes me a little irritated.

Is there a way to update warning information of webstorm program? I think that there's a way to register node js or mongodb api list to webstorm program, but I can't find it by searching.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any warnings being shown for this code. What does this error look like?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same problem, and I have found it to be a reference to the javascript .each() method which is in fact deprecated. The simplest (read quick fix) way to resolve this, is to place "//noinspection JSDeprecatedSymbols" above the line giving the error. You can alternatively click on the lightbulb icon on the left, goto "inspection Deprecated Javascript symbol options", then Suppress for statement (or any other option you may wish to use to disable this warning)

```
var findRestaurants = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor =db.collection('restaurants').find( );
    //noinspection JSDeprecatedSymbols
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            console.dir(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the list of functions present in MongoDB engine for Node.JS. There two function that can replace "each" function: "next" and "hasNext".

So for your example, I would write this code:

```
var findRestaurants = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('restaurants').find( );
    var parseRestaurant = function() {
        cursor.next(function(err, restaurant){
            if (err)
                return console.error(err);
            console.dir(doc);
            hasNextRestaurant();
        });
    };

    var hasNextRestaurant = function() {
        cursor.hasNext(function(err, result){
            if (err)
                return console.error(err);

            if (result)
                parseRestaurant();
            else {
                //Here is the last point of iterations
                //We can use this for statistics output
                return console.log('That\'s all');
            }
        });
    };

    hasNextRestaurant();
}
```

Or something like this:

```
var findRestaurants = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('restaurants').find( );
    var parseRestaurant = function(err, doc) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err);
        console.dir(doc);
        cursor.hasNext(checkNext);
    };

    var checkNext = function(err) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err);

       if (result)
            parseRestaurant();
        else {
            //Here is the last point of iterations
            //We can use this for statistics output
            return console.log('That\'s all');
        }
        cursor.next(parseRestaurant);
    };

    cursor.hasNext(checkNext);
}
```